# Need a regex for a decimal number which doesn't accepts second dot

Tags: regex

I am using this regex `^(\d{1,5}|\d{0,5}\.\d{1,2})$` for decimal validation, but it is accepting (45.5.) this value

Requirement: While he is entering second dot itself we need to show error message, can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: `45.5.` [is not matched](https://regex101.com/r/xwqkS7/1), Your code must be wrong, show it.

Comment: Actually it is used in angular for custom validation, here is my code                              This is my ts file:                                                                                          
         import {AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';

export  function DecimalValidator(control:AbstractControl):{
    [key:string]:any
} |null{
    const valid = /^\d{0,10}(\.\d{2,})?$/.test(control.value);
    return valid ? null : { invalidDecimal: { valid: false, value: control.value } };
}

Answer (score 0):

Your post contains actually **two different** regexes:

- `^(\d{1,5}|\d{0,5}.\d{1,2})$` - in the question,
- `^\d{0,10}(\.\d{2,})?$` - in a comment.

I tried also the second (see https://regex101.com/r/MFetJ3/1/) and it also
**doesn't** match (like the first regex).

In order to have match, you should:

- remove the second dot from the source text,
- change `{2,}` to `{1,}` - accept even a **single** digit after the first dot.